# How to do freehand drawing in Google Maps on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, drawing, polygon, google-maps-sdk-ios

In drawing application we can identify when the user is starting to draw and moving the finger to make a line/shape. I'm trying to do the same on a map, how can I do this?

Comment: HI, actually right even i am trying the same, can you help me out if you found anything?

Comment: @Liv a: Have u find any solution on this ? One way is to put a button which enables/disables map scrolling. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 13):

Basic steps will involve:

1)**Add a overlay view whenever user starts to draw.**

```
lazy var canvasView:CanvasView = {

    var overlayView = CanvasView(frame: self.googleMapView.frame)
    overlayView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    overlayView.delegate = self
    return overlayView

}()
@IBAction func drawActn(_ sender: AnyObject?) {

    self.coordinates.removeAll()
    self.view.addSubview(canvasView)
    let origImage = UIImage(named: "pen")
    let tintedImage = origImage?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
    drawBtn.setImage(tintedImage, for: .normal)
    drawBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white
    drawBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

}
```

2)**Do free hand drawing in the overlay view**.

```
class CanvasView: UIImageView {

    weak var delegate:NotifyTouchEvents?
    var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
    let brushWidth:CGFloat = 3.0
    let opacity :CGFloat = 1.0


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        if let touch = touches.first {

            self.delegate?.touchBegan(touch: touch)
            lastPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        }
    }


    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first  {

            self.delegate?.touchMoved(touch: touch)
            let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)
            lastPoint = currentPoint
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first  {

            self.delegate?.touchEnded(touch: touch)

        }
    }

    func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        self.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))

        context?.move(to: fromPoint)
        context?.addLine(to: toPoint)

        context?.setLineCap(.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(brushWidth)
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        context?.setBlendMode(.normal)
        context?.strokePath()

        self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        self.alpha = opacity
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    }

}
```

3)**Get all coordinates in an array from OverlayView to Controller using delegate pattern**

```
//MARK: GET DRAWABLE COORDINATES
extension ViewController:NotifyTouchEvents{

    func touchBegan(touch:UITouch){

        let location = touch.location(in: self.googleMapView)
        let coordinate = self.googleMapView.projection.coordinate(for: location)
        self.coordinates.append(coordinate)

    }

    func touchMoved(touch:UITouch){

        let location = touch.location(in: self.googleMapView)
        let coordinate = self.googleMapView.projection.coordinate(for: location)
        self.coordinates.append(coordinate)

    }

    func touchEnded(touch:UITouch){

        let location = touch.location(in: self.googleMapView)
        let coordinate = self.googleMapView.projection.coordinate(for: location)
        self.coordinates.append(coordinate)
        createPolygonFromTheDrawablePoints()
    }
}
```

4)**Change that coordinates into a polygon**.

```
   func createPolygonFromTheDrawablePoints(){

        let numberOfPoints = self.coordinates.count
        //do not draw in mapview a single point
        if numberOfPoints > 2 { addPolyGonInMapView(drawableLoc: coordinates) }//neglects a single touch
        coordinates = []
        self.canvasView.image = nil
        self.canvasView.removeFromSuperview()

        let origImage = UIImage(named: "pen")
        let tintedImage = origImage?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
        drawBtn.setImage(tintedImage, for: .normal)
        drawBtn.tintColor = UIColor.red
        drawBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    }

    func  addPolyGonInMapView( drawableLoc:[CLLocationCoordinate2D]){

        isDrawingModeEnabled = true
        let path = GMSMutablePath()
        for loc in drawableLoc{

            path.add(loc)

        }
        let newpolygon = GMSPolygon(path: path)
        newpolygon.strokeWidth = 3
        newpolygon.strokeColor = UIColor.black
        newpolygon.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        newpolygon.map = googleMapView
        if cancelDrawingBtn.isHidden == true{ cancelDrawingBtn.isHidden = false }
        userDrawablePolygons.append(newpolygon)
        addPolygonDeleteAnnotation(endCoordinate: drawableLoc.last!,polygon: newpolygon)
    }
```

I have created a demo project for drawing/deleting multiple polygons on Google Map in Swift 3 [here](https://github.com/anishparajuli555/FreeHandMapDrawing.git).

**Remember setting API key in AppDelegate and changing bundle identifier in order to run the project.**

Comment: how I can fine drawable circle inner restaurant or some place

Comment: you need to check if lat long lies inside the path/polygon

Comment: if any demo available

Comment: @AnishParajuli웃 Parajuli, have you updated this code into the latest Swift. If you have then it will be great help to me.

Answer (score 2):

[Map Kit Polyline or Polygon Drawing - https://github.com/tazihosniomar/MapKitDrawing](https://github.com/tazihosniomar/MapKitDrawing)

This link contains demo project for drawing polygons on Apple Map. But, logic remains the same for Google Map View. So, you can copy implementation logic from this and apply it on Google Map.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a line use `polyline`. Refer to [Google Maps Shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/shapes).
To use `polyline` you need to give locatoin coordinates. To convert a point on screen to coordinate use `coordinateForPoint:(CGPoint)point` method of [GMSProjection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_projection) class.

`Polyline` actually draws a line between two coordinates. Thus, with moving mapView those lines will move, too. I think this is what you want.

Comment: @liva I wonder how it can be implemented because when user put a finger on screen and drag it, how would you decide whether user wants to scroll around a map to see another location or wants to draw some picture?