# Get array of CGPoint while user wants to draw a line

Tags: ios, google-maps, cgpoint

I am using google map for my ios app, what i want to achieve is like when user touches the map and drags the finger, then identify the coordinates and draw the line on the map and then want to get all the marker inside that polyline(circular). So for that i had to disable the movement of the map which i did as below:

```
_googleMapView.settings.scrollGestures = NO;
_googleMapView.settings.zoomGestures = NO;
```

But then now i want to draw a line for which i got this link as below:

[Free hand drawing in google maps-iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132266/google-map-for-ios-draw-line-by-user)

This link says that i have to do as follows:

To draw a line use polyline. Refer to Google Maps Shapes.

To use polyline you need to give locatoin coordinates. To convert a point on screen to coordinate use coordinateForPoint:(CGPoint)point method of GMSProjection class.

But my problem is i want to get the CGPloint of array when user drags and the map(which inturn will make a polyline), but i am really unaware of how will i get the CGPoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/saru2020/SARMapDrawView

This project did exactly what i wanted, helpful link.